# ng-include with ng-click raise submit - how to avoid it?

Tags: angularjs, angular-leaflet-directive

I have html template:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController">
  <form novalidate>
    Name: <input type="text" ng-model="user.name" />
    <button ng-click="greet(user)">GREET</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

And I add it like this:

```
"<div ng-include src=\"'/views/template.html'\"></div>"
```

This is function in `MyController`:

```
$scope.user = {}
    $scope.greet = function (user) {
        alert('hello ' + user.name)
    }
```

But when I click on button it makes submit it doesn't call greet function.
I also tried to add `type="button"` to it but it is the same.
[Here is the working solution](http://tombatossals.github.io/angular-leaflet-directive/examples/0000-viewer.html#/markers/angular-template-example) so I don't know what I am missing.

Comment: I tried the code you provided, and no submit of form on my side. Probably in the application you have another handler which forces the form submission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `type="submit"` with the submit button, and `input` instead of `button`.

Comment: I tried that it also maked postback. In the example that I added it's the same code I added.

Comment: I've recreated this scenario in plunker, seems to be working fine:
http://plnkr.co/edit/PEElwQLyTZRLK536pwFv?p=preview

Comment: You are right it works. This is probably some issue with template and popup in this directive. When I try same code without template it works but in template it doesn't.